# Checkbox inline with label using the composer

Tags: solspace-freeform

I would like to get the label and checkbox inline using composer.

This is the current code rendered by the `{composer:field_output}` tag:

```
<div class="unit size1of1">
  <label for="freeform_newsletter">
    Newsletter
  </label>
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="newsletter" value="n">
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="y" id="freeform_newsletter">
  </p>
</div>
```

But I'd like it to render something like this, still using the `{composer:field_output}` tag while selecting all items containing checkboxes:

```
<label  for="freeform_newsletter" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="hidden" name="newsletter" value="n">
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="y" id="freeform_newsletter"> Newsletter
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to manually write that out instead of use the composer tag.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should do it.

```
{if composer:field_type == 'checkbox'}
    <label{if composer:field_name != ''} for="freeform_{composer:field_name}"{/if} class="checkbox-inline">
        {if composer:field_required}
            {freeform:field:{composer:field_name} attr:required="required"}
        {if:else}
            {freeform:field:{composer:field_name}}
        {/if}
        {composer:field_label}{if composer:field_required}<span class="required">*</span>{/if}
    </label>
{if:else}
    {if composer:field_required}
        {freeform:field:{composer:field_name} attr:required="required"}
    {if:else}
        {composer:field_output}
    {/if}
{/if}
```